# How to set selected value from drop down in angular 4

Tags: angular, select, selection, dropdown

How to populate the selected values of drop down along with image . I have images defined in my css file as shown below. On selection, only the text gets populated, but not the image. How can i make image also get populated along with the text
[image]

[image]

```
<div class="transportDropdown input-field">
            <select>
              <option value="1">Home</option>
              <option value="2">Transport</option>
            </select>
          </div>


    ngOnInit() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.transportDropdown select').formSelect();

      });
    }


.transportDropdown li:first-child span{
     background-image: url(../images/pfm_home_grey.svg);

}
.transportDropdown li:nth-child(2) span{
     background-image: url(../images/pfm_cars_grey.svg);
}
```

Comment: ahhh don't mix jquery with angular. It'll mess up your code

Comment: But how do i populate the image as well along with the text. As you can see, I have selected Home, but only the text gets populated and not with the image.

Comment: @Nancy Are you able to create a StackBlitz that demonstrates the issue please?

Comment: I have created stackBlitz, but I am not sure how to add images before Home and Transport .  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vujprf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Just use an image off the internet such as [this](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=67r6l6Lr&id=9F2A1AF8E483C9B98225E534E410A8D4665E7710&thid=OIP.67r6l6LrI4A7u9Fp3uF8mAHaHa&mediaurl=http%3a%2f%2fdownloadicons.net%2fsites%2fdefault%2ffiles%2fhome-home-icon-80046.png&exph=512&expw=512&q=house+icon&simid=608016742977572248&selectedIndex=14&ajaxhist=0) The reason I ask, is because your CSS rule above is not for a select, it's for a list, so I'm not sure what that first image represents...

Comment: Thats right , the image i have added is in css file , and it is for the drop down list. As a result, when I select the option , only the text get populated and not the image. I need to move the image from css to html so that when i select , both image and text gets populated. How can i do that?

Comment: I need the stackblitz to reproduce that problem, so it should include the dropdown, the select, and any code you're using

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vujprf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: @Nancy That still doesn't include any image or list...

Comment: I have added the style for image in HTML and css as per my local code. Please check now.

Comment: @Nancy I just checked, and it doesn't seem to have changed? Did you save the changes? Has the URL changed or anything?

Comment: Its the same URL. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vujprf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: There is no `ul` element in there, nor are there any images. If its easier for you to upload your project to GitHub, I can take a look at that, but as it stands I don't really know what your use case is or what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: I have created a separate question with the requirement mentioned . Please check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224532/how-to-select-drop-down-values-in-angular-4?noredirect=1#comment93335915_53224532