# How to add a new row on click of a button in angular 4

Tags: angular, button, click, row, addition

[image]I have the below code to create a row and a button Add Person. On click of Add person , i want to create one more row with Person 2, Person 3 and so on.
[image]  . How can I achieve it.

```
<div class="splitTheBill-row">
        <div class="splitTheBill-left">
          <div class="userIcon">
            <div class="splitTheBill-user">
              <img src="assets/images/person.png" alt="My Profile">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field national-id pull-left">
              <input id="form3" class="form-control" type="text">
              <label for="form3" class="">Person 1</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="splitTheBill-right">
          <div class="input-field national-id pull-left">
            <input id="form4" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="addperson-btncont">
        <div class="reg-submitCont">
          <button url="#" class="btn-secondary waves-effect waves-light btn">Add Person</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the form creation in the component, please ?

Comment: I am not using any forms to create this. This is a part of my HTML code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `*ngFor` to loop through your persons, like so:

```
  <div class="splitTheBill-left">
    <div *ngFor="let person of persons">
      <div class="userIcon">
        <div class="splitTheBill-user">
          <img src="assets/images/person.png" alt="My Profile">
        </div>
        <div class="input-field national-id pull-left">
          <input id="form3" class="form-control" type="text">
          <label for="form3" class="">{{person.name}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then, you can create an array in the TS that represents the people:

```
  persons = [
      {"name": "Person 1"}
  ]
```

And to add a new row, all you need to do is push a new person into that array

```
  this.persons.push({"name": "Person " + (this.persons.length + 1)})
```

[Take a look at the official tutorial for more info](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2)

Comment: It adds Person 2 , Person 2 everytime on click of a button. Ideally i want Person 2, Person 3, Person 4, Person 5 ....

Comment: @Nancy, using ReactiveForms will be a better approach for your case.

Comment: @Nancy That;'s because the name was hardcoded. I've just updated the answer

Comment: It creates Person 1 twice and then Person 2 , Person 3, Person 4... I have added a image as well.

Comment: There should be a `+1` in that code as well (I updated it), take a look at the example, it should be `"Person " + (this.persons.length + 1)})`

Comment: You are just awesome .. Prompt response. Thanks a lot .:) Can u take a look at this question if possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53220405/how-to-set-selected-value-from-drop-down-in-angular-4?noredirect=1#comment93327826_53220405

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for here is a Reactive Form that could add person(s) on the fly to the form:

Here's a minimal Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="personsForm" (submit)="onFormSubmit()">
  <div formArrayName="persons">
    <div *ngFor="let person of persons; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
      Name: <input type="text" formControlName="name"><br>
      Amount: <input type="text" formControlName="amount">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" (click)="addPerson()">
    Add Person
  </button>
  <button>
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Here's the Component Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component(...)
export class AppComponent {
  personsForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.personsForm = this.fb.group({
      persons: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  onFormSubmit() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.personsForm.value));
  }

  addPerson() {
    (<FormArray>this.personsForm.get('persons')).push(this.fb.group({
      name: [],
      amount: []
    }));
  }

  get persons() {
    return (<FormArray>this.personsForm.get('persons')).controls;
  }
}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-person-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.