# How to select drop down values in angular 4

Tags: angular, select, dropdown, populate

I have a select drop down where in i need to populate the selected value from API and the other options are hardcoded. On select of an option , I need to populate it along with the icon. After selection , the color of the option selected should be in blue color ( both text and icon ) with a tick mark besides it. How can i achieve this.[image]

Above image shows the pre population of data ( both text and icon )from API.

[image]

Above image shows on click of a drop down, a tick mark is shown with change in text and icon color.
Below is the code I have tried.

```
 <select> 
          <option value="">{{ selectedTransResult.category }}</option>      
          <option value="1">Home</option>
          <option value="2">Transport</option></select>
```

Comment: can you share your code of what you have tried?

Comment: updated question with code